# Matlab convert imtransform (usinv Udata anv Vdata) to simulink's apply geometric transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink, image-rotation, rotational-matrices

I rotate a 2D matrix using 3D angles (rotational matrix) with this code:

```
rX = 5; rY = 3; rZ = 4;

rot_mat_Z = [cosd(rZ),-sind(rZ), 0; sind(rZ),cosd(rZ), 0; 0, 0, 1]; 
rot_mat_Y = [cosd(rY), 0, sind(rY); 0, 1, 0; -sind(rY), 0, cosd(rY)]; 
rot_mat_X = [1, 0, 0; 0, cosd(rX), -sind(rX); 0, sind(rX), cosd(rX)];

rot_m = rot_mat_Z * rot_mat_Y * rot_mat_X;
tform= maketform('projective', rot_m');

image_rotate = imtransform(image_in, tform, 'udata',[0 1],'vdata',[0 1],'size',size(image_in));
```

This works on matlab and I get the result I want.

Now I need to apply the same transformation on simulink. How can I do this?

I tried the "Apply Geometric Transformation" block, using rot_m but I get a weird image.

I probably need to modify rot_m but how?

Comment: Check out example code in vision.GeometricTransformer System object. That should have similar interface as the block. http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.geometrictransformer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I never found any way to do this easily in Simulink. I had to write and compile a custom c function.